# Error using userEvent with React Testing Library and react-select AsyncSelect (but only in CodeSandbox?)

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-select, codesandbox, user-event

I created this CodeSandbox so I could demonstrate a problem with related code (the onChange not firing in a test):

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-tree-xkw8s?file=/src/App.test.js

However in CodeSandbox I can't even get that far because as soon as I call

```
userEvent.type(securityField, 'abc{enter}')
```

I get a set this error in the console:

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.]
```

and as a result the loadOptions callback of `AsynSelect` is never triggered (locally I'm not having any issue with that, just the onChange which isn't firing).

I have not been able to find any examples of or guidance on this error. I haven't used CodeSandbox a lot so maybe I'm missing something basic.

I am not seeing this error in my local environment but I am trying to solve it because I want to finish setting up my original problem.

Comment: Did you happen to get it sorted out? Your sandbox tests are running fine for me!

Comment: I did not. Did you check the console? The tests are green but there are errors in the console that prevent any further expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [react-select-event](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-react-select-event/) for interacting with your react-select in testing. This was made specifically for testing with react-testing-library.

Comment: Hard to believe I never found that after all the time I spent trying to fix this. Thanks Steve!